# Temporary main activity android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities in my app one is sign up and the other is the one that a person will use after he has created an account. I want to show the sign up launcher activity until the person signs up. My code:

```
    private static boolean doesDatabaseExist(ContextWrapper context,
    String dbName) {
   File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(dbName);
   return true; 


  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (doesDatabaseExist == true) { 
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_sign_up) ; }
    else {setContentView (R.layout.activity_name1); }}
```

Is this the right approach??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the best method, it will make your activity code very messy.

You have two options 
1 - Use Fragments - Instead of two activities, use two fragments. When your launcher activity loads, you can then check if your database exists and from there programmatically load the correct fragment which contains all your view code.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

if (doesDatabaseExist()){
          Name1Fragment fragment = new Name1Fragment ();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }else{
       SignUpFragment fragment = new SignUpFragment ();
       fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
       fragmentTransaction.commit();

  }
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

2 - Use a Splash screen - If you want to keep your code in separate activities rather than moving them to fragments, you can set your main launcher to load a splash screen and from there check if your database exists and from that value you can launch the correct activity.

```
    if (doesDatabaseExist()){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Name1Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }else{
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignUpActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);

  }
```

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: it was that simple. I feel stupid. I am going with the 2nd solution because i have two activities.

Comment: Haha no problem, glad to help. Please accept this as the correct answer :D

Comment: You might want to check out my answer also, its a lot more comprehensive in that it it directs you down the path of writing a more flexible/'best practices' app, etc. Though you would still use the above 'Splash Screen' approach when they load the application to direct them to the Account Create/Login Activity

Answer (score 0):

In essence you have the right idea... but this is not the 'right' implementation.

The 'right' approach is to use a couple things it appears that you are not.

1) Content Provider (This is 'wraps' your database and creates a 'simple'(well defined) interface to interact with your database. (well 'simple'... to use, to -write it- can be a pain... until you learn how to make them easily, and my tip to make it easy is to make a Schema file before you start that contains all the structure of your underlying database + the ContentProvider [Here is a sample Schema](https://github.com/mawalker/POSA-14/blob/master/assignments/week-7-assignment-6/iRemember/src/edu/vuum/mocca/provider/MoocSchema.java) we have used previously in some of our Coursera Android Concurrency/Mobile/Web Specialization courses.) )

2) Android's Built in Account management support.

The POINT of using a ContentProvider and the following components, is multi-purpose... You are following best practices... You have well defined 'Separation of Concerns'... You are a "good neighbor" application that allows the user to disable your application from syncing when they don't want the application to sync...(saving both battery/bandwidth/memory(from your application not running a service 24/7 to sync otherwise)) You don't actually have to write the 'sycning' mechanism or timers or anything like that... (You DO have to write the custom 'logic' for your sync process...and that is beyond the scope of this question...)

When you just use the built-in SyncAdaptor/Account mechanisms... You can easily check to see if the user has an 'account' when they open the 'main activity' and then direct them to create a new account/login to an existing account before they continue. (The code below doesn't actually use 'web-based accounts' like OAuth/Google/Facebook/StackOverflow/etc. But if you don't have a web-server with authentication setup... this can be a good early testing measure until you do, that still allows you to use the Accounts mechanisms/etc. And once you do, you obviously have to change them to use the right info.)

(There are a lot of reasons why this approach is better, and I'm kinda skimming over them, to save time/space... but I think you'll get the general 'gist' of it.)

2.1) An AccountAuthenticatorService that extends **Service**

2.2) An Activity that extends **AccountAuthenticatorActivity**

Here are two 'sample' files that should help you write your own versions. This code is years old, but should still be 'close' to what you need. I use some 'tricks' in this code (like: ApplicationConstants) that I'm not going to share because they aren't a best practices. But the general outline of these files should get you 70%~80%+ of the way there.

If you need help writing a ContentProvider, my personal recommendation is to buy/borrow/get a copy of [Professional Android 2 Application Development **2nd Edition**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470565527) For ~5.50$ USD. This is the older version of the book that was written to teach for Android 2.0, but the core parts of what you are trying to do haven't changed since then, and it cuts the price from the new version drastically.  This book is what I personally used to learn this material and I think it does one of the best jobs in teaching you how to start from scratch and make a DB and ContentProvider. You can always download [the Downloadable Code from this book](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Android-2-Application-Development.productCd-0470565527,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html) if you don't want to buy the book. It has a lot (in Chapter_7.txt) of examples of the different parts of a content provider. However, it doesn't explain what each one does... So it won't be -as- useful as having both.

```
package edu.vuum.mocca.authentication;

import edu.vuum.mocca.main.ApplicationConstants;
import android.accounts.AbstractAccountAuthenticator;
import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountAuthenticatorResponse;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.accounts.NetworkErrorException;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Skeleton example for how a functional SyncAdaptor's
 * AccountAuthenticatorService would be implemented.
 * 
 * @author Michael A. Walker
 * 
 */
public class AccountAuthenticatorService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = AccountAuthenticatorService.class
            .getCanonicalName();
    private static AccountAuthenticatorImpl sAccountAuthenticator = null;

    private static String ACCOUNT_NAME;
    private static String ACCOUNT_TYPE;

    public AccountAuthenticatorService() {
        super();
        ACCOUNT_NAME = ApplicationConstants
                .getValue(ApplicationConstants.ACCOUNT_NAME);
        ACCOUNT_TYPE = ApplicationConstants
                .getValue(ApplicationConstants.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
    }

    public static Account GetDefaultSyncAccount() {
        final String accountName = ACCOUNT_NAME;
        return new Account(accountName, ACCOUNT_TYPE);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.app.Service#onBind(android.content.Intent)
     */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        IBinder ret = null;
        if (intent.getAction().equals(
                android.accounts.AccountManager.ACTION_AUTHENTICATOR_INTENT))
            ret = getAuthenticator().getIBinder();
        return ret;
    }

    /**
     * Creates Singleton AccountAuthenticator Implementation.
     * @return
     */
    private AccountAuthenticatorImpl getAuthenticator() {
        if (sAccountAuthenticator == null)
            sAccountAuthenticator = new AccountAuthenticatorImpl(this);
        return sAccountAuthenticator;
    }

    private static class AccountAuthenticatorImpl extends
            AbstractAccountAuthenticator {
        private Context mContext;

        public AccountAuthenticatorImpl(Context context) {
            super(context);
            mContext = context;
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see
         * android.accounts.AbstractAccountAuthenticator#addAccount(android.
         * accounts.AccountAuthenticatorResponse, java.lang.String,
         * java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], android.os.Bundle)
         */
        @Override
        public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response,
                String accountType, String authTokenType,
                String[] requiredFeatures, Bundle options)
                throws NetworkErrorException {
            Bundle result = new Bundle();
            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, AccountLoginActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE,
                    response);
            result.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, i);
            return result;
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see
         * android.accounts.AbstractAccountAuthenticator#confirmCredentials(
         * android.accounts.AccountAuthenticatorResponse,
         * android.accounts.Account, android.os.Bundle)
         */
        @Override
        public Bundle confirmCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response,
                Account account, Bundle options) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i(TAG, "confirmCredentials, not supported, exception thrown.");
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see
         * android.accounts.AbstractAccountAuthenticator#editProperties(android
         * .accounts.AccountAuthenticatorResponse, java.lang.String)
         */
        @Override
        public Bundle editProperties(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response,
                String accountType) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i(TAG, "editProperties, not supported, exception thrown.");
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see
         * android.accounts.AbstractAccountAuthenticator#getAuthToken(android
         * .accounts.AccountAuthenticatorResponse, android.accounts.Account,
         * java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)
         */
        @Override
        public Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response,
                Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options)
                throws NetworkErrorException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i(TAG, "getAuthToken");
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            // TODO this works, but isn't really doing any valid auth. 
            bundle.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, account.name);
            return bundle;
        }

        /**
         * Ask for a localized label for the given authTokenType.
         * <p>
         * may return null if not known.
         * 
         * @see android.accounts.AbstractAccountAuthenticator#getAuthTokenLabel(java
         *      .lang.String)
         */
        @Override
        public String getAuthTokenLabel(String authTokenType) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i(TAG, "getAuthTokenLabel, not supported, exception thrown.");
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        /*
         * Checking features of the Account Not Supported currently.
         * 
         * @see
         * android.accounts.AbstractAccountAuthenticator#hasFeatures(android
         * .accounts.AccountAuthenticatorResponse, android.accounts.Account,
         * java.lang.String[])
         */
        @Override
        public Bundle hasFeatures(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response,
                Account account, String[] features)
                throws NetworkErrorException {
            Log.i(TAG, "hasFeatures, not supported, exception thrown.");
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see
         * android.accounts.AbstractAccountAuthenticator#updateCredentials(android
         * .accounts.AccountAuthenticatorResponse, android.accounts.Account,
         * java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)
         */
        @Override
        public Bundle updateCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response,
                Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i(TAG, "updateCredentials, not supported, exception thrown.");
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a sample AccountLoginActivity that extends **AccountAuthenticatorActivity**

```
package edu.vuum.mocca.authentication;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountAuthenticatorActivity;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import edu.vanderbilt.mooc.mooc_cp.R;
import edu.vuum.mocca.main.ApplicationConstants;

/**
 * Activity that gets Launched when Adding an Account to the SyncManager
 * <p>
 * An Activity to prompt for a Server Address, a UserName, and a Password. Uses
 * these to verify user login credentials and to create a 'token' identifying
 * the user account on the device.
 * 
 * @author Michael A. Walker
 * @Date 2012-11-23
 */
public class AccountLoginActivity extends AccountAuthenticatorActivity {

    public final static String LOG_TAG = AccountLoginActivity.class.getCanonicalName();

    /**************************************************************
     * UI component variables
     *************************************************************/
    EditText mServerIP;
    EditText mUsername;
    EditText mPassword;
    Button mLoginButton;

    /**************************************************************
     * Examples of constants for message passing on the AsyncTask
     *************************************************************/
    public final static String PARAM_AUTHTOKEN_TYPE = "";
    public final static String PARAM_ACCOUNT_TYPE = "";

    /*
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate() called");
        setContentView(R.layout.authenticator_layout);

        mServerIP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.server);
        mUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        mLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

        // might be able to make this go away and be in the XML
        // just easier to put here for now.
        mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginButtonPressed(v);
            }
        });
    }

    // start the background threaded action to authenticate the user
    public void loginButtonPressed(View v) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate() called");
        String user = mUsername.getText().toString().trim()
                .toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
        String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim()
                .toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);

        String testValue = ApplicationConstants
                .getValue(ApplicationConstants.ACCOUNT_TYPE);

        if (testValue != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "testValue: " + testValue,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (user.length() > 0 && password.length() > 0) {
            LoginTask t = new LoginTask(AccountLoginActivity.this);
            t.execute(user, password);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is the background logic behind the user login credentials checking
     * 
     * @author Michael A. Walker
     * 
     */
    private class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        Context mContext;
        ProgressDialog mDialog;

        // constructor
        LoginTask(Context c) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "LoginTask() constructed");
            mContext = c;
            mLoginButton.setEnabled(false);
            // display a dialog with a spinner showing progress being worked on
            mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(c, "",
                    getString(R.string.authenticating), true, false);
            mDialog.setCancelable(true);
        }

        // Threaded background work (doesn't block UI)
        @Override
        public Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "LoginTask.doInBackground() called");
            String user = params[0];
            String pass = params[1];

            // TODO:Do something internetty HERE
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Bundle result = null;
            Account account = new Account(user,
                    mContext.getString(R.string.ACCOUNT_TYPE));
            AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(mContext);
            if (am.addAccountExplicitly(account, pass, null)) {
                result = new Bundle();
                result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
                result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
                setAccountAuthenticatorResult(result);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // post processing of login verification
        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "LoginTask.onPostExecute() called");
            mLoginButton.setEnabled(true);
            mDialog.dismiss();
            if (result)
                finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i can't believe you wrote this.Thanks for the explanation. I understood some stuff and will try to implement it.

Comment: this is from a github repo 
well, 
how to use appcompat activity, if u know,  instead of AccountAuthenticatorActivity ?